# gulp-jasmine-browser and test coverage

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, code-coverage, istanbul

Has anyone used gulp-jasmine-browser with phanotomjs and istanbul for coverage successfully? gulp-jasmine-browser doesn't have official support for coverage.